# In superset, unable to star with my own ip address. Its taking default ip address i.e http://127.0.0.1:8088/

Tags: apache-superset

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqtnU.png)

Configured in Ubuntu of superset, unable to star with my own ip address. Its taking default ip address i.e http://127.0.0.1:8088/.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the command like this:

```
superset run -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8088
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gunicorn. For example:

```
$ gunicorn -w 4 -b <your_ip_addr>:<port_num> "superset:app"
```